# BroadcastReceiver is not being called from AndroidManifest on BOOT_COMPLETE in Android

Tags: android

In my Android application I want to run a `Service` without opening/running my application. For that I have extended `BroadcastReciever` class. But this `BroadcastReceiver` class is not being called from `AndroidManifest.xml` on `BOOT_COMPLETE`. So please tell what is the problem in my code? Or is there any other way to run a `Service` without opening my application? I have checked the control flow of my code and whole the code is working perfectly, the problem is that `BroadcastReceiver` is not being called.

**Part of AndroidManifest.xml file:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<service android:name=".HelloService"
         android:exported="false"/>

<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastreceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**MyBroadcastreceiver.java class**

```
package com.example.abc.project1;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyBroadcastreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        /*this is not being called*/
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, HelloService.class);
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: why did you set `android:exported="false"` for?

Comment: same result even after removing that. @KhalidovOleg

Comment: did you try to remove `android:exported="false"` for `HelloService` as well?

Comment: The Broadcast for Boot_Completed takes some time to be fired by Android OS after restart. On some devices it can take up to 5 Minutes until the BroadcastReveiver receives the actual Event.

Comment: I have tried to wait up to 10 minutes. @Pfennigbaum

Comment: Can you check if the path to MyBroadcastReceiver is correct? Maybe you can specify the full path instead of using ".MyBroadcastReceiver" in Android manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `android:exported="false"` from the `<receiver>`. That says you do not want anyone (other than yourself) sending a broadcast to this receiver. As a result, your receiver will be ignored by the system.

Beyond that, you also need an activity and to have run that activity before trying to reboot the device. You may already have that, but I thought that I would mention it for completeness.

Comment: still same result. @CommonsWare